# How to set up two loggers one too append and the other to overwrite?

Tags: python, logging

I am trying to set up two loggers that log info in an while loop. I want the first logger `'event_logger'` to append information, whilst the second logger `'status_logger'` needs to overwrite the file each time with the current status. This is how I have set them both up, but both logs are appending information and the `'status_logger'` fails to overwrite each time. What am I doing wrong here?

```
## event log
event_logger = logging.getLogger('event_log')
event_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
event_logger_handler = logging.FileHandler(f'{datetime.now().date()}_event_log.log', mode='a')
event_logger_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
event_logger.addHandler(event_logger_handler)

## status log
status_logger = logging.getLogger('status_log')
status_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
status_logger_handler = logging.FileHandler(f'{datetime.now().date()}_status_log.log', mode='w+')
status_logger_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
status_logger.addHandler(status_logger_handler)
```